# WPF designing custom UI component for Silverlight/Windows Phone 7

Tags: .net, wpf, user-interface, windows-phone-7

I am looking into designing completely custom UI component mainly for Windows Phone 7 applications and possible later for web based applications (Silverlight). It would be something like speedometer with some effects i.e. when speed changes arrow slowly moves too.

How do these completely custom UI components are designed? Visual Studio or maybe even Blend is used for that?

Are there are good tutorials around the web which would guide me in creating such component?

I imagine it completely written with WPF/XAML, that it would be vectorial and could scale on my needs.

Thanks for the help,
-david

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create reusable UserControls in Silverlight for Windows Phone. Here's a walkthrough.

[Snowfall (User Control Sample) : Windows Phone 7 Tutorials](http://compiledexperience.com/windows-phone-7/tutorials/snowfall)

Answer (score 0):

Do you know at least basics of WPF? Well, if you did, you would probably know how to write UserControls :)

So my advice: learn at least basics of WPF and XAML. Come back for advice, if you get stuck.

And yes, you use VS and/or Blend. (Blend especially for more graphically intensive/advanced controls).

There are many Introduction to WPF tutorials around there. But be prepared to unlearn what you know about UI design/creation. But your effort will be generously rewarded, WPF is quite hard to get into, but awesome once you get hang of it.

Comment: I did worked with WPF/XAML, remember handcrafting those XAML files. Using C#/.NET, even PowerShell for writing applications. Also used Bled, but very little. But that those some time ago (2-3 years, I think) and worked on different technologies. It's time to go back little by little. I tink a lot of changed, but gonna be fun.